# virtual machine object cannot find or load Main class

Tags: java, virtual-machine

so i have problem where i am trying to open a file through my own written  virtual machine object in java but the problem is that the virtual machine is not running and causing an error.

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\dell\Trace\Main.java

we also tried modifying the CLASSPATH & PATH with no success

below is the code of the main

```
import com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.*;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Trace {

    // Running remote VM
    private final VirtualMachine vm;

    // Thread transferring remote error stream to our error stream
    private Thread errThread = null;

    // Thread transferring remote output stream to our output stream
    private Thread outThread = null;

    // Mode for tracing the Trace program (default= 0 off)
    private int debugTraceMode = 0;

    //  Do we want to watch assignments to fields
    private boolean watchFields = false;

    // Class patterns for which we don't want events
    private String[] excludes = {"java.*", "javax.*", "sun.*", 
                 "com.sun.*"};

    /**
     * main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Trace(args);
    }

    /**
     * Parse the command line arguments.  
     * Launch target VM.
     * Generate the trace.
     */
    Trace(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    int inx;
    for (inx = 0; inx < args.length; ++inx) {
        String arg = args[inx];
        if (arg.charAt(0) != '-') {
        break;
        }
        if (arg.equals("-output")) {
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[++inx]));
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open output file: " + args[inx]
                       + " - " +  exc);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        } else if (arg.equals("-all")) {
        excludes = new String[0];
        } else if (arg.equals("-fields")) {
        watchFields = true;
        } else if (arg.equals("-dbgtrace")) {
        debugTraceMode = Integer.parseInt(args[++inx]);
        } else if (arg.equals("-help")) {
        usage();
        System.exit(0);
        } else {
        System.err.println("No option: " + arg);
        usage();
        System.exit(1);
        }
    }
        if (inx >= args.length) {
        System.err.println("<class> missing");
            usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(args[inx]);
        for (++inx; inx < args.length; ++inx) {
            sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(args[inx]);
        }
        vm = launchTarget(sb.toString());
        generateTrace(writer);
    }


    /**
     * Generate the trace.
     * Enable events, start thread to display events, 
     * start threads to forward remote error and output streams,
     * resume the remote VM, wait for the final event, and shutdown.
     */
    void generateTrace(PrintWriter writer) {
        vm.setDebugTraceMode(debugTraceMode);
        EventThread eventThread = new EventThread(vm, excludes, writer); 
        eventThread.setEventRequests(watchFields);
        eventThread.start();
        redirectOutput();
        vm.resume();

        // Shutdown begins when event thread terminates
    try {
        eventThread.join();
        errThread.join(); // Make sure output is forwarded 
        outThread.join(); // before we exit
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        // we don't interrupt
    }
    writer.close();
    }   

    /**
     * Launch target VM.
     * Forward target's output and error.
     */
    VirtualMachine launchTarget(String mainArgs) {
    LaunchingConnector connector = findLaunchingConnector();
    Map arguments = connectorArguments(connector, mainArgs);
        try {
        return connector.launch(arguments);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            throw new Error("Unable to launch target VM: " + exc);
        } catch (IllegalConnectorArgumentsException exc) {
            throw new Error("Internal error: " + exc);
        } catch (VMStartException exc) {
            throw new Error("Target VM failed to initialize: " +
                exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void redirectOutput() {
        Process process = vm.process();

        // Copy target's output and error to our output and error.
        errThread = new StreamRedirectThread("error reader",
                                             process.getErrorStream(),
                                             System.err);
        outThread = new StreamRedirectThread("output reader",
                                             process.getInputStream(),
                                             System.out);
        errThread.start();
        outThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Find a com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch connector
     */
    LaunchingConnector findLaunchingConnector() {
        List connectors = Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().allConnectors();
        Iterator iter = connectors.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Connector connector = (Connector)iter.next();
            if (connector.name().equals("com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch")) {
                return (LaunchingConnector)connector;
            }
        }
        throw new Error("No launching connector");
    }

    /**
     * Return the launching connector's arguments.
     */
    Map connectorArguments(LaunchingConnector connector, String mainArgs) {
        Map arguments = connector.defaultArguments();
        Connector.Argument mainArg = 
                       (Connector.Argument)arguments.get("main");
        if (mainArg == null) {
            throw new Error("Bad launching connector");
        }
    mainArg.setValue(mainArgs);

    if (watchFields) { 
        // We need a VM that supports watchpoints
        Connector.Argument optionArg = 
        (Connector.Argument)arguments.get("options");
        if (optionArg == null) {
        throw new Error("Bad launching connector");
        }
        optionArg.setValue("-classic");
    }
    return arguments;
    }

    /**
     * Print command line usage help
     */
    void usage() {
    System.err.println("Usage: java Trace <options> <class> <args>");
    System.err.println("<options> are:");
    System.err.println(
"  -output <filename>   Output trace to <filename>");
    System.err.println(
"  -all                 Include system classes in output");
    System.err.println(
"  -help                Print this help message");
    System.err.println("<class> is the program to trace");
    System.err.println("<args> are the arguments to <class>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well where is the `Main` class defined? How do you try to start it?

Comment: trace is the main class ,and we start it trough command line by passing the main of the java class we want to trace and this application uses a virtual machine to run the class

Comment: Well, stupid question but have you made sure the remote JVM also has this class in its classpath?

Comment: How do you try to run it? `java C:\Users\dell\Trace\Main.java`? What Java version?

Comment: well to be honest this is not my code this is given to me as an university assignment and  i am supposed to create some graphs on it but i am trying to fix this error to make it happen but in short words,this is how i am writing it ```java Trace -output C:\Users\dell\Trace\one.txt 
 C:\Users\dell\Trace\Main.java```

Comment: java version jdk 8

Comment: Dici can you please explain how thats done ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: i am using IntelliJ

Comment: Try `java Trace -output C:\Users\dell\Trace\one.txt` from `C:\Users\dell`

Comment: @daniu it didnt work budd